# Get paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner due connection (Python)

Tags: python, windows, console, remote-access, fabric

Python 3.7
Fabric 2.4.0
Can't connect remote PC
using port 3389 (like mstsc), if i'm trying another port - get "Unable to connect to port  on "

```
v = Connection(host=ServName, port=Port, user=User, connect_kwargs={'password': 's3cr3t'})
print(v.is_connected) #get False
v.run('dir') #get error (see img attach below)
```

[image: Image of the error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port 3389 is typically used for windows RDP and not for ssh.  You might be trying to connect via WinRM (usually ports 5985-86) in which case use the [pywinrm library](https://pypi.org/project/pywinrm/) and not fabric.  You're better off using ansible which has this connectivity baked in.